# Create element for each div with a particular class

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I have a couple of divs with a "isVideo" class. I can successfully attach a click event with a for loop, but I also need to create a span within each div. This is what I have:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("isVideo");
     for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
     videos[i].addEventListener('click', playVideo, false);
     var playBtn =  videos[i].createElement("span");
     playBtn.appendChild(videos[i]);
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/garethj/pen/bpxVKX

Comment: You are creating a span then appending the video div to it. You need to do videos[i].appendChild(playBtn) to get the span inside the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are `appending` div inside `span`. You need to append `spanElement` inside `divElement`

---

```js
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("isVideo");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  videos[i].addEventListener('click', playVideo, false);
  var playBtn = document.createElement("span");
  videos[i].appendChild(playBtn);
}
```

**Edit:** Also change `videos[i].createElement` to `document.createElement` as `videos[i]` does not have method `createElement`

### [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNLxXb)

Comment: thanks, I am getting ideos[i].createElement is not a function

Comment: @user1059511, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

It should be done in the opposite way.

Replace

```
playBtn.appendChild(videos[i]);
```

with

```
videos[i].appendChild(playBtn);
```

Comment: makes sense, but I now get : videos[i].createElement is not a function

Comment: what is the value of `videos[1]` before calling createElement?

Comment: <a href="#" class="isVideo"></a> for each element with the class

Comment: @user1059511 in your codepen, you have not defined `playvideo`. Can you share updated pen after defining the same?